Gas fireplace self-extinguishing
We just moved into a home with a Harman Shadowlight XL Gas Fireplace insert. We've gotten the propane tank filled and followed the lighting instructions that are attached to the base of the fireplace - pilot light ignites and stays lit, we are able to turn the fireplace on, and the fire appears to burn normally for around 30 seconds. However, it then slowly extinguishes itself, at which point the pilot light cannot be relit for several hours. My guess is that there's a flue or vent closed somewhere, causing the fire to quickly consume all the available oxygen. This is the first gas fireplace I've ever owned, so I would not be surprised if I'm missing something extremely simple. Thanks in advance for any assistance!


Update:
Took me quite some time to get someone to take a look at this, as the servicers in my area were very busy during the pre-winter season. The issue ended being a faulty thermocouple - the serviceman replaced the entire pilot light assembly and since then the fireplace has been working wonderfully. Not something I would have been comfortable working on myself, so this was never going to be DIY solution.

Good for your solution, BUT add the solution as a proper answer so the site works as it should.

What you are describing can be explained if your propane tank's valve is turned off, but not very tightly. The gas line slowly fills with gas under pressure, but as soon as you start using it, the pressure drops and the flame slowly fades.
Check the tank valve.
You might try turning it clockwise (off), and if it won't turn, that confirms the diagnosis. To remedy the situation, turn it counterclockwise (on/open) all the way until it stops. Don't force it.
If this doesn't fix the problem, you likely have a problem with the gas pressure regulator, and a service call is recommended.
Please let us know.

I am reasonably confident that I had tried this, but I'll check again when I get home from work. Thanks for your response!

Confirmed that the gas valve on the propane tank was fully opened. Some additional details - when burning, the glass seems to fog up significantly on the inside. In addition, I noticed a click that I had not caught previously that preceded the gas being cut off. Any other suggestions beyond calling someone out?

Make sure you have a working carbon monoxide detector in the vicinity before you try anything else. You should be able to swing the glass open by releasing a catch. I'd suggest that you try lighting the fireplace with the glass open, and plan to run it for no more than 4-5 minutes for safety reasons. If it remains lit with the glass open but reliably extinguishes itself in 30 seconds with the glass closed, you have a blocked flue. You should not run the fireplace any more until the flue is unblocked and the flame remains lit with the glass closed.

I've accepted your answer as I think I've gone about as far as I am comfortable with this - I'm happy to fiddle with a pellet stove all day, but I don't want to mess with gas. Time to call someone I suppose. Thanks again!

@toprock30 If you would post the ultimate cause and resolution of the problem when you know it, It would be useful for future questioners with a similar issue. I have two gas fireplaces and they both produce fogging on the glass when started cold, but it clears quickly. My money is on the gas regulator as the ultimate cause. Good luck.

I'll be sure to do so!

Finally got someone out to take a look, added an update to my original post. Thanks again for taking the time to respond to this!
